# Composed layout with fixed header in Android

Tags: android, layout

In my app I have a counter that I would like to keep on all screen's headers, it increments itself every few second so it should live independently from the other components in the view. Only the "body" view must change.

I thought about having a parent activity and playing with fragments but I'm not sure how to resize them to compose my screens.

Would this be the way to go or I would rather use simple views ?

Answer (score 0):

> create different layout for header or footer and use   layout="@layout/main" />in ur layout file in top and bottom
>   respectively
>
> if u use the same layout file and change the center layout then the
>   code become dirty so try the above code to do this

Comment: ok but I have an animated counter incrementing on the header, I don't want to reconstruct it every time I change the current activity. I want to dissociate the counter header from the content, so I can call updateView on the body without touching the header.